# how to send html content at place of thymeleaf template name

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I want to send html content in email as text and want to bind some variables into this html content. this html content is saved in my database which i used to send email. so i want to use **SpringTemplateEngine's  process method** which accept template name, and context variables. but i have html content not a template. i want to use thymeleaf template engine for this. but i doesn't understand how can i convert html content for example :

```
<html>
<head></head>
<title></title>
<body>
<div>
<p>Your ${value1} for ${value2}</p>
</div
</body>
```

to thymeleaf template by using following method:

```
String mailTemplate = templateEngine.process("mailTemplate", context);
```

Please someone help me to overcome this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an **StringTemplateResolver** which we can use to send html content as string at place of template name.

For example:

> Configure your template resolver and template engine

```
private ITemplateResolver stringTemplateResolver() {
    final StringTemplateResolver templateResolver = new StringTemplateResolver();
    templateResolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
    return templateResolver;
}

@Bean
public TemplateEngine emailTemplateEngine() {
    final SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
    templateEngine.addTemplateResolver(stringTemplateResolver());
    return templateEngine;
}
```

and use this in your email service. this solved your problem.

Comment: Hello kind sir, would you know how to do both at the same time? Make the engine when you call .process. Treat the string either as a path or as content?

Comment: @vibetribe93 you can use Qualifier annotation for differentiate beans

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Already did it like that. But since the template engine is resource "expensive" I wasn't satisfied having two instances of it. Is there a way to do it with just a single instance?

Comment: @vibetribe93 you can create two bean of TemplateEngine

Comment: Thank you so much. I just made a research of whole day and after that it worked.